# What does the following Javascript function do?

Tags: javascript, menu

Please tell me how the following code is working and what the code exactly do ?
the code is a portion of shutter menu by javascript, from the website: http://www.menucool.com/horizontal/menu-code?menu=50&skin=3&p=1

```
if (k == -1 && /:\/\/(?:www\.)?[^.\/]+?\.[^.\/]+\/?$/.test) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].getAttribute("maptopuredomain") == "true") {
      k = i;
      break;
    }
  }
```

the code is hoisted in the following link

http://brainsoftcoder.com/jscssmenu.php

Answer (score 0):

This piece of Javascript code creates a syntax error. With non-descriptive variables, no clue what is in those variables and without context where this piece of code is within the entire file, it is not possible to tell what this piece of code is supposed to do and what it's function is within the menu. I may hope you know what `if` and `for` do.